# How do I grant my Google Cloud service account access to G Suite?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I have a [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/) service account that I want to enable to read the emails of my [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/) account. However, when I follow [the prescribed procedure](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority) of authorizing the service account as a client in the G Suite admin interface (Security -> Manage API client access), the form fails with the error 'This client name has not been registered with Google yet.'. I supply the client ID of my service account key file for client name.

[image]

What am I supposed to supply for client name, so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the service account, one has to enable "Google Apps domain-wide delegation" if it is to access G Suite. It was kind of poorly explained in the Google documentation. Otherwise my procedure was correct, one is supposed to use the `client_id` field from the credentials JSON file.

Comment: When I go to enable that option, it tells me that `To change settings for G Suite domain, product name for the OAuth consent screen must be configured.` That seems to conflict with the whole point of this domain-wide delegation option which is supposed to `Allows this service account to be authorized to access all users' data on a G Suite domain without manual authorization on their part.`.  Am I missing something, or is it just a very confusing contradiction on Google's part?

Comment: Turns out you do just need to create the Oauth consent screen even if no one will see it.  This whole process was incredibly confusing to me, so I documented the step-by-step instructions in case anyone else finds it helpful: https://www.fin.com/eng-blog/navigating-the-google-suite-directory-api